# Find the missing dates and fill with with the help of other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime

I have a two dataframes
df1:

```
Country_Code    FY  Churned_month   Churned_Subscribers Resubscribed_month  Resubscribed_Subscribers
  AU           FY12   Apr-2012             1                 0                   0.0
  AU           FY12   Jul-2012             6               Jul-2012              3.0
  AU           FY13   Apr-2013             1                 0                   0.0
  AU           FY13   Aug-2013            13                 0                   0.0
  AU           FY13   Nov-2012             1                 0                   0.0
  AU           FY14   Jan-2014             1               Jun-2014              1.0
  AU           FY15   Apr-2015            45               Apr-2015             22.0
  AU           FY15   Apr-2015            45               Jun-2015              7.0
  AU           FY15   Apr-2015            45               May-2015              6.0
  AU           FY15   Aug-2015            14               Aug-2015              5.0
  AU           FY15   Feb-2015            17               Apr-2015              3.0
  AU           FY15   Feb-2015            17               Feb-2015             10.0
  AU           FY15   Feb-2015            17               Jun-2015              1.0
```

df2:

```
  start_date    end_date    fy_year_vc
  2021-09-01    2022-08-31  FY22
  2020-10-28    2021-08-31  FY21
  2019-09-01    2020-10-27  FY20
  2018-09-01    2019-08-31  FY19
  2017-09-01    2018-08-31  FY18
  2016-09-01    2017-08-31  FY17
  2015-09-01    2016-08-31  FY16
  2014-09-02    2015-08-31  FY15
  2013-09-12    2014-09-01  FY14
  2012-09-04    2013-09-11  FY13
  2011-12-12    2012-09-03  FY12
  2010-10-18    2011-12-11  FY11
  2009-10-05    2010-10-17  FY10
```

I want to apply df2 to df1 for finding the missing month in the Churned_month column

For example: For Churned_month Apr-2012 check the end date in df2 for FY FY12 which is 2012-09-03 so the the missing month diffrence is May-2012, Jun-2012, July-2012, Aug-2012,Sep-2012 till september as the end date is 2012-09-03. Therefore, the resultant dataframe looks like this:

```
 Country_Code    FY  Churned_month   Churned_Subscribers Resubscribed_month  Resubscribed_Subscribers
    AU           FY12   Apr-2012             1                Apr-2012            0.0
    AU           FY12   May-2012             0                May-2012             0
    AU           FY12   June-2012            0                Jun-2012             0
    AU           FY12   Jul-2012             0                July-2012            0
    AU           FY12   Aug-2012             0                 Aug-2012            0
    AU           FY12   Sep-2012             0                Sep-2012             0
    AU           FY12   Jul-2012             6               Jul-2012              3.0
    AU           FY13   Apr-2013             1                 0                   0.0
```

I am not able to figure out how to achieve this. I tried with setting index as Churned_month but get the desired output. Please help

Comment: Why is there a duplicate row `Jul-2012` churned month for `FY_12`, one with 0 churned subscribers and one with 6 churned subscribers? Shouldn't it only be the row with 6 churned subscribers?

Comment: Also what should happen to the three `Apr-2015` rows for `FY15`? is there a daterange between that start date and the end date in df2 repeating three times in the resultant dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

For both df1 and df2, it will be easier if you standardize the format of the date time columns (and floor them to the beginning of the month).

```
## floor each month
df1['Churned_month'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Churned_month']).dt.to_period('M').dt.to_timestamp()
df2['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['start_date']).dt.to_period('M').dt.to_timestamp()
df2['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['end_date']).dt.to_period('M').dt.to_timestamp()
```

Then you can loop through each row of `df1`, creating a monthly date range between the `Churned_month` column of that row to the `end_date` of the corresponding row in df2. From this, you can construct the values in the other columns of the resultant DataFrame. At the end, you can then drop any duplicate rows.

```
result = pd.DataFrame(columns=
    ['Country_Code', 'FY', 'Churned_month', 'Churned_subscribers', 'Resubscribed_month', 'Resubscribed_Subscribers']
)

for row in df1.itertuples(index=False):
    start_date = row[2]
    end_date = df2.loc[df2['fy_year_vc'] == FY, 'end_date'].max()
    new_months = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='MS')
    churned_subs, resubscribed_subs = [], []
    for month in new_months:
        if month == start_date:
            churned_subs.append(row[3])
            resubscribed_subs.append(row[5])
        else:
            churned_subs.append(0)
            resubscribed_subs.append(0)
    new_df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Country_Code': [row[0]]*len(new_months),
        'FY': [row[1]]*len(new_months),
        'Churned_month': new_months,
        'Churned_subscribers': churned_subs,
        'Resubscribed_month': new_months,
        'Resubscribed_Subscribers': resubscribed_subs
    })
    result = pd.concat([result, new_df])

result.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)
result['Churned_month'] = result['Churned_month'].dt.strftime('%b-%Y')
result['Resubscribed_month'] = result['Resubscribed_month'].dt.strftime('%b-%Y')
```

Here is the `result` DataFrame:

```
>>> result
  Country_Code    FY Churned_month Churned_subscribers Resubscribed_month  Resubscribed_Subscribers
0           AU  FY12      Apr-2012                   1           Apr-2012                       0.0
1           AU  FY12      May-2012                   0           May-2012                       0.0
2           AU  FY12      Jun-2012                   0           Jun-2012                       0.0
3           AU  FY12      Jul-2012                   0           Jul-2012                       0.0
4           AU  FY12      Aug-2012                   0           Aug-2012                       0.0
5           AU  FY12      Sep-2012                   0           Sep-2012                       0.0
0           AU  FY12      Jul-2012                   6           Jul-2012                       3.0
0           AU  FY13      Apr-2013                   1           Apr-2013                       0.0
1           AU  FY13      May-2013                   0           May-2013                       0.0
2           AU  FY13      Jun-2013                   0           Jun-2013                       0.0
3           AU  FY13      Jul-2013                   0           Jul-2013                       0.0
4           AU  FY13      Aug-2013                   0           Aug-2013                       0.0
5           AU  FY13      Sep-2013                   0           Sep-2013                       0.0
0           AU  FY13      Aug-2013                  13           Aug-2013                       0.0
0           AU  FY13      Nov-2012                   1           Nov-2012                       0.0
1           AU  FY13      Dec-2012                   0           Dec-2012                       0.0
2           AU  FY13      Jan-2013                   0           Jan-2013                       0.0
3           AU  FY13      Feb-2013                   0           Feb-2013                       0.0
4           AU  FY13      Mar-2013                   0           Mar-2013                       0.0
5           AU  FY13      Apr-2013                   0           Apr-2013                       0.0
0           AU  FY14      Jan-2014                   1           Jan-2014                       1.0
1           AU  FY14      Feb-2014                   0           Feb-2014                       0.0
2           AU  FY14      Mar-2014                   0           Mar-2014                       0.0
3           AU  FY14      Apr-2014                   0           Apr-2014                       0.0
4           AU  FY14      May-2014                   0           May-2014                       0.0
5           AU  FY14      Jun-2014                   0           Jun-2014                       0.0
6           AU  FY14      Jul-2014                   0           Jul-2014                       0.0
7           AU  FY14      Aug-2014                   0           Aug-2014                       0.0
8           AU  FY14      Sep-2014                   0           Sep-2014                       0.0
0           AU  FY15      Apr-2015                  45           Apr-2015                      22.0
1           AU  FY15      May-2015                   0           May-2015                       0.0
2           AU  FY15      Jun-2015                   0           Jun-2015                       0.0
3           AU  FY15      Jul-2015                   0           Jul-2015                       0.0
4           AU  FY15      Aug-2015                   0           Aug-2015                       0.0
0           AU  FY15      Apr-2015                  45           Apr-2015                       7.0
0           AU  FY15      Apr-2015                  45           Apr-2015                       6.0
0           AU  FY15      Aug-2015                  14           Aug-2015                       5.0
0           AU  FY15      Feb-2015                  17           Feb-2015                       3.0
1           AU  FY15      Mar-2015                   0           Mar-2015                       0.0
2           AU  FY15      Apr-2015                   0           Apr-2015                       0.0
0           AU  FY15      Feb-2015                  17           Feb-2015                      10.0
0           AU  FY15      Feb-2015                  17           Feb-2015                       1.0
```